# Type Mismatch When Using VBA CountIF()

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am attempting to use the Countif() formula to get a count, but I keep getting an error of

> Type mismatch

What is incorrect in this VBA syntax that is causing the issue?

```
With Sheets("Symbiot").ListObjects("Symbiot")
  salecount  = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.ListColumns(1).Range, .ListColumns(1).Range, venuename, .ListColumns(5).Range, ">=" & entryd, .ListColumns(5).Range, "<=" & exitd)
End With
```

Comment: remove the first `.ListColumns(1).Range,` It is used in SUMIFS but not COUNTIFS

Comment: your syntax is wrong, should be range, criteria as many as you need.  https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Comment: AH - such a simple fix.  Thank you both!